# Retrieve day when the date is given

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, datetime

When given the year, month and the date, I want to retreive the day the date belongs to. Is there a function available in ActionScript for this?

```
Input : 
Year : 2012
Month : 11
Date : 29

Output : Thursday
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get fancy, you can also output a day name that is specific to your user's locale:

```
        var d:Date = new Date(2012, 10, 29); // November 29, 2012
        trace ("The day of week (number) is: ", d.day); // outputs: The day of week (number) is:  4
        var f:DateTimeFormatter = new DateTimeFormatter( LocaleID.DEFAULT, DateTimeStyle.SHORT, DateTimeStyle.SHORT);
        f.setDateTimePattern("EEEE");
        trace(f.format(d)); // outputs: "Thursday"
```

EDIT:

I used the Flash class `flash.globalization.DateTimeFormatter`, but there are also Flex specific classes for this too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok Finally I got it working. In Date() constructor it seems the index for the year and the day is the same but the month index should be -1;

```
//this returns Day of September 1st. Not August 1st.
var d:Date = new Date(2012,8,1); 
Alert.show(" "+d.day);
```

Comment: yes... month is a zero based index.  Also you should mark Sunil's answer as correct... your own answer here doesn't show how to make it say "Thursday" which is what you specifically asked for in your question.  Sunil showed you how to do that with a formatter.